# disable submit btn until input field is fill

Tags: javascript, html

hi i want to disable submit button until Date and location field is inserted once the date and location field is inserted button can be pressed.

i cant find how please need help on this

```js
(function() {
  
    var cause = document.getElementById('cause');
    var amount = document.getElementById('amount');
    var currency = document.getElementById('currency');
    var datepicker = document.getElementById('datepicker');
    var adults = document.getElementById('adults');
    var children = document.getElementById('children');
    
    var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
  
    btn.addEventListener('click', async (e) => {
      var occupancy = $('input:radio[name=occupancy]:checked').val();
      var buggy = $('input:radio[name=atv]:checked').val();
      e.preventDefault();
      fetch('/checkout_sessions', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          cause: cause.value,
          datepicker: datepicker.value,
          adults: adults.value,
          children: children.value,
          currency: currency.value,
          occupancy: occupancy,
          buggy: buggy,
          amount: parseInt(amount.value * 100, 10),
        }),
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((session) => {
        stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      });
    });
  })();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
        <style>
            .small-img-group {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            }

            .small-img-col {
            flex-basis: 24%;
            cursor: pointer;
            }

            .counter1 {
            float: left;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            overflow-y: hidden;
            }

            .counter2 {
            float: left;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            overflow-y: hidden;
            padding-left: 15px;
            }

            .up,
            .down {
            display: inline-block;
            color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
            font-size: 29px;
            margin: 1px 1px;
            cursor: pointer;
            width: 23px;
            line-height: 14px;
            height: 26px;
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: bold;
            border: 1px solid orangered;
            user-select: none;
            }
            .ui-state-highlight, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-highlight {
              border: 1px solid #dad55e;
              background: orangered;
              color: #ffffff;
            }

            .up:hover,
            .down:hover {
            color: #fd0b3f;
            text-align: center;
            }

            .adults {
            padding-right: 5px;
            }

            .children {
            padding-right: 5px;
            }

            input {
            appearance: none;
            height: 28px;
            text-align: center;
            width: 63px;
            line-height: 24px;
            font-size: 20px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            border-color: orangered;
            }

            input[type="radio"] {
            display: none;
            }

            label[for=private] {
            position: relative;
            color: orangered;
            font-size: 20px;
            border: 2px solid orangered;
            border-radius: 5px;
            align-items: left;
            display: flex;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin-right: 10px;
            }

            label[for=shared] {
            position: relative;
            color: orangered;
            font-size: 20px;
            border: 2px solid orangered;
            border-radius: 5px;
            align-items: left;
            display: flex;
            cursor: pointer;
            }
            label[for=withatv] {
            position: relative;
            color: orangered;
            font-size: 20px;
            border: 2px solid orangered;
            border-radius: 5px;
            align-items: left;
            display: flex;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin-right: 10px;
            }

            label[for=withoutatv] {
            position: relative;
            color: orangered;
            font-size: 20px;
            border: 2px solid orangered;
            border-radius: 5px;
            align-items: left;
            display: flex;
            cursor: pointer;
            }

            input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
            background-color: orangered;
            color: white;
            }

            input[type="radio"]:checked+label:before {
            height: 16px;
            width: 16px;
            border: 10px solid white;
            background-color: orangered;
            }
        </style>
        
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="container sproduct my-5 pt-5">
        <div class="row mt-5">
          <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-12 col-12">
            <img class="img-fluid w-100 pb-1" src="https://skylandtourism.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Morning-Safari.jpg" alt="" id="MainImg" width="450">
      
            <div class="small-img-group">
              <div class="small-img-col">
                <img src="https://media.tacdn.com/media/attractions-splice-spp-674x446/09/99/99/87.jpg" width="100%" class="small-img" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="small-img-col">
                <img src="https://skylandtourism.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Morning-Safari.jpg" width="100%" class="small-img" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="small-img-col">
                <img src="https://skylandtourism.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Morning-Safari.jpg" width="100%" class="small-img" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="small-img-col">
                <img src="https://skylandtourism.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Morning-Safari.jpg" width="100%" class="small-img" alt="">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-12">
            <h6 style="padding-top: 20px;">Home / Morning Safari</h6>
            <h3>Morning Safari</h3>
            <h2><label> Total AED:</label><input type="number" id="amount"class="total Price" readonly></label></h2>
            <p><input type="text" id="datepicker" style="width: 120px;" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Date" readonly/></p>
            <div class="counter1">
              <Label class="Adults">Adults</Label>
              <div class='down' onclick='decreaseCount(event, this)'>-</div>
              <input id="adults" type='text' value='1' readonly>
              <div class='up' onclick='increaseCount(event, this)'>+</div>
            </div>
            <div class="counter2">
              <Label class="Children">Children</Label>
              <div class='down' onclick='decreaseCount2(event, this)'>-</div>
              <input id="children" type='text' value='0' readonly>
              <div class='up' onclick='increaseCount(event, this)'>+</div>
            </div>
            <div style="display: flex; width: 100%">
              <input type="radio" name="occupancy" id="private" value="private" checked="checked" onclick="updateTotal()">
              <label for="private" style="width: 74px;">Private</label>
              <input type="radio" name="occupancy" id="shared" value="shared" onclick="updateTotal()">
              <label for="shared" style="width: 74px;">Shared</label>
            </div>
            <div style="display: flex; width:100%">
             <input type="radio" name="atv" id="withatv" checked="checked" onclick="updateTotal()">
             <label for="withatv" style="width: 94px;">With ATV</label>
             <input type="radio" name="atv" id="withoutatv" onclick="updateTotal()">
             <label for="withoutatv" style="width: 119px;">Without ATV</label>
            </div>
            <input class="location" type="text" placeholder="location">
            <div class="field">
              <label for="cause">Cause</label>
              <select id="cause">
                <option value="cause-a">cause a</option>
                <option value="cause-b">cause b</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
              <label for="currency">Currency</label>
              <select class="field" id="currency">
                <option value="cad">CAD</option>
                <option value="eur">EUR</option>
                <option value="usd">USD</option>
              </select>
            </div>         
          
            <div class="field">
              <button type="submit" id="btn">Donate</button>
            </div>
      
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      
        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.ui.datepicker.mobile.css" /> 
        <script src="jQuery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.ui.datepicker.mobile.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        
        <script src="donate.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script>
             
            function increaseCount(e, el) {
                var input = el.previousElementSibling;
                var value = parseInt(input.value, 10);
                value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
                value++;
                input.value = value;
                updateTotal();
            }

            function decreaseCount(e, el) {
            var input = el.nextElementSibling;
            var value = parseInt(input.value, 10);
            if (value > 1) {
                value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
                value--;
                input.value = value;
                updateTotal();
            }
            }

            function decreaseCount2(e, el) {
            var input = el.nextElementSibling;
            var value = parseInt(input.value, 10);
            if (value > 0) {
                value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
                value--;
                input.value = value;
                updateTotal();
            }
            }

            $('#datepicker').datepicker({
                minDate:0
            })

            var MainImg = document.getElementById('MainImg');
            var smallimg = document.getElementsByClassName('small-img');

            smallimg[0].onclick = function() {
            MainImg.src = smallimg[0].src;
            }
            smallimg[1].onclick = function() {
            MainImg.src = smallimg[1].src;
            }
            smallimg[2].onclick = function() {
            MainImg.src = smallimg[2].src;
            }
            smallimg[3].onclick = function() {
            MainImg.src = smallimg[3].src;
            }

            function calculateTotal() {
              const privateAdultPrice = 100;
              const sharedAdultPrice = 40;
              const privateChildrenPrice = 50;
              const sharedChildrenPrice = 30;

              const withAtvAdultPrice = 100;
              const withAtvChildrenPrice = 80;

              const noAtvPrice = 0;

              const adults = +document.querySelector('#adults').value;
              const children = +document.querySelector('#children').value;

              const isPrivate = document.getElementById('private').checked;
              const isWithAtv = document.getElementById('withatv').checked;
              
              const adultTripPrice = isPrivate ? privateAdultPrice : sharedAdultPrice;
              const childrenTripPrice = isPrivate ? privateChildrenPrice : sharedChildrenPrice;
              const adultVehiclePrice = isWithAtv ? withAtvAdultPrice : noAtvPrice;
              const childrenVehiclePrice = isWithAtv ? withAtvChildrenPrice : noAtvPrice

              const adultPrice = adults * (adultTripPrice + adultVehiclePrice)
              const childrenPrice = children * (childrenTripPrice + childrenVehiclePrice)

              return adultPrice + childrenPrice;
            }
            function updateTotal() {
              const total = calculateTotal();
              console.log(total);
              document.querySelector('#amount').value = total;
            }
            updateTotal();

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

hi i want to disable submit button until Date and location field is inserted once the date and location field is inserted button can be pressed

i cant find how please need help on this

Comment: i have but in my case things got little messed up stripe is also placed in javascript so makes me little confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to add a conditional in your click event listener:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', async (e) => {
  var occupancy = $('input:radio[name=occupancy]:checked').val();
  var buggy = $('input:radio[name=atv]:checked').val();
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!datepicker.value || !location.value) return;
  // ...
```

Aside: you don't actually appear to be including location in your form submission. You'd need to add code to get the input:

```
var location = document.querySelector('.location');
```

This should go with all of your other variables like `datepicker`. This is using the class name of the input...you don't have an `id` on that input. It would be good to add an `id` actually...

If you want something that actually causes the button to be greyed out, you'd want to add event listeners to the inputs in question, to check when they've been filled in to add/remove the disabled attribute:

```
datepicker.addEventListener('change', e=> {
  btn.disabled = datepicker.value && location.value;
});
location.addEventListener('change', e=> {
  btn.disabled = datepicker.value && location.value;
});

// also set the state initially, when the page loads
btn.disabled = datepicker.value && location.value;
```

These boolean expressions take advantage of an empty string being "falsy". However even a single space character will make the value "truthy." If you want to make sure word characters have actually been entered, you'd need a different test, perhaps a regex, such as `datepicker.value.match(/\S+/)`, which checks for at least one non-space character.

One other thing worth mentioning: if you actually had a `<form>` element surrounging your inputs and button, you'd want to be sure to handle the `submit` event on the form. A form can be submitted by other means besides clicking a button, such as hitting enter while an input is focused.

Comment: tried first one button is not working even when field are filled

Comment: You're probably getting a JavaScript error because you weren't including `location` on your form submission. I edited my answer to make note of this. Also if you're not familiar with browser developer tools, you should definitely use them. `F12` in most browsers should open them. You'll see errors and such show up in the `console`, these can be very helpful for debugging.

Comment: POST http://localhost:4242/ajax.php?v=1640612965872 404 (Not Found)
send @ jquery.js:8706
ajax @ jquery.js:8136
jQuery.<computed> @ jquery.js:8282
(anonymous) @ content.js:15
inner.html:1 [Violation] 'load' handler took 530ms

Comment: datepicker.addEventListener('change', e=> {
  btn.disabled = datepicker.value && location.value;
});
location.addEventListener('change', e=> {
  btn.disabled = datepicker.value && location.value;
});

// also set the state initially, when the page loads
btn.disabled = datepicker.value && location.value;

where do i add this if i want grey out button

Answer (score 0):

first you have to check that both fields are not empty, so you can get their value and see if they are undefined or not. After that, you can remove the "disabled" attribute with `element.removeAttribute("disabled");`

Comment: can you demonstrate pls i cant figure it out